# Use Ngx-translate to translate data stored in Mysql DB

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am trying to translate dynamic data stored in a Mysql database using Ngx-translate, but i have no idea how to go about it. I know how configure ngx-translate and translate preset data in lang.json files but that is for static information. How do i do it for dynamic information? Is it possible to use google translate API on Angular apps?

Comment: Translating text which is stored on backend side should be translated on backend side. Why do you need it to be translated on frontend?

Comment: Ngx it is only on the frontend side it has nothing to do with data stored in Backend there you need a translator for backend.

Comment: @RomanŠimík I would like to translate information that is feed to my database. I thought Ngx could be used to translate the data fetch from the DB using a toggle i.e from English to French as per the user's language  preference

Comment: @SteveGaita Better way of doing that is, when the front-end will request the data from the database, it should also append (eg. custom header, which will tell which language is user using) and based on that backend will translate that data to that language and send it back to front-end